# Can I track where a file is hosted? (PDF, ePub, AZW)

Tags: security, pdf, tracking

More specifically, PDF, ePuB or AZW (Publishing formats). For example if an original document was downloaded and uploaded elsewhere (an unauthorised upload), is there any feasible way to tell me where? Ideally I'd like to receive basic data such as URL,  server IP and approximate upload date.

I've looked at similar posts whereby users are looking to track statistics when a pdf is downloaded and used, however I'm purely looking to track its online whereabouts in a unobtrusive way.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I definitely recommend using [Google dorks](https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/use-google-hack-googledorks-0163566/) as they are very useful for finding information online. You can specify the filename in the URL ten add the publishing extension and some unique text related to the document. The approximate date of creation is cached in google itself. You can derive the IP address from the domain name using the command `nslookup` on Windows/OSX/Linux.

The [google](https://google.com) search query would look something like this:

```
inurl:"filename" & filetype:pdf & allintext:"some unique content of the document"
```